# Compile mex function with external libraries

Tags: c++, matlab, linker, mex

I'm trying to generate a mex function usigin external libraries. I'm using Ubuntu 18 and Matlab R2021a.

In particular I want to  compile my file.cpp that uses my cpp library called model.
What I did is

```
mex -I<path_library_include> -L<path_library_so_file> -lmodel.so -lboost_system -lstdc++ file.cpp -v
```

where in -I i put the path where is the include of the library in -L the path in which the libmodel.so is located, then I added 2 more libraries and at the end the source file that I want to compile.

In this way I can compile my source but when I try to execute the mex function I get:

> libmodel.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I also tested the library outside matlab and works fine, this is the command that I use to compile the library outside Matlab

```
gcc -Wall -I<path_library_include> -L<path_library_so_file> main.cpp -lmodel -lboost_system -lstdc++ -o main
```

What could be the problem with Matlab?

Comment: There is no any problem with Matlab. You should use ldconfig for setting library search paths, or LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable, or use static linkage with model.a.

Comment: I already set LD_LIBRARY_PATH with the path where the so file is placed. The problem is just at run time because during the compilation I don't get any errors

Comment: The error "libmodel.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" says clearly you did not set LD_LIBRARY_PATH properly.

Comment: What I did is `export LD_RUN_PATH=$LD_RUN_PATH:<path_library_so_file>` I am sure that the path is correct.
Is it correct in this way ?

Comment: Are you kidding? RUN is not LIBRARY.

Comment: sorry I just copied the wrong command but I did the same with  LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` works with MATLAB. But if you set it in a terminal window, and then open MATLAB by clicking on an icon somewhere, then your environment variable will not be set for MATLAB. Start MATLAB from the same terminal where you set the path, or change the path globally.

Comment: In MATLAB you can do `getenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH')` to see if the variable is set correctly in the MATLAB process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to 273K that gave me the right direction.
The problem was that the LD_LIBRARY_PATH was not configured well in fact running `/sbin/ldconfig -v` my library was not present. So to add the shared library i created a new file as root in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` called `mylib.conf` it is not important the name just the extension. Then I run

```
sudo ldconfig
```

after that the library was present in fact running

```
/sbin/ldconfig -v | grep  model
```

where model is the name of my library. it is possible to see the output.